# Как сделать "уведомление" в админ панели Django

Tags: html, django

На сайте есть страница с новостями, там же кнопка "Предложить новость", в ней пользователь жмет на кнопку "Отправить" и мне надо так что бы в Admin панели было что то похожее на уведомление где можно нажать "Принять" или "Отклонить", если администратор нажмет Принять то в БД sqlite в раздел news должна занестись новость, как такое сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать модель, новость:

```
class Novost(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Создатель')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Текст')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата')
```

создаём обычную форму с полями, далее
в views:

```
def novost_add(request):
    form = Form()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            novost = form.save()
            return redirect(куда надо)
    return render(request, 'адрес.html', {'form':form})
```

пишем нужный шаблон.